# Which data structure is suitable for efficient searching and minimum possible memory?

Tags: data-structures, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I want to develop an application to maintain the inventory of different products. Products are divided into different categories. The number of categories are fixed but products in each category can increase/decrease depend on introducing new products. When new product will arrive it will be added to its category, if product will already in any category then only its quantity will update.

From array, singly linked list and doubly linked list, Which data structure is most suitable to build this application? Searching of product should be efficient and application should take minimum possible memory.

Comment: Is this A) something you're actually doing, B) an exercise from a textbook, or C) some kind of online contest or interview question?

Comment: Option B, actually this was an academic question. I just want to understand this scenario.

Comment: And have you thought about it? What operations must you perform on the container? Do you know how efficient those operations are on the the three containers you mention (and perhaps others)? Do you know how to add a new element to an array or to a list?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being tangential, but best suited seems to be a Map.

```
Map<Category, Map<Product, Integer>> map ..
```

Unless this is some academic assignment, I cannot think of any real world scenario where maps are not applicable.

Yes you may have issues around concurrency, distributed caches, eventual consistencies, in-memory store being flushed randomly, but they would exist even for array and linkedlists.

Comment: Thanks, actually this was an academic question. I just want to understand it.

Comment: arrays of categories ( since they dont change ) and then linkedlist with head's stored in arrays should help. this is like HashMap